# Json problems to csv

Tags: python, json, csv, export-to-csv, export-to-excel

I'm trying to get some stats from the NBA stats page. I'm following this tutorial-idea 
https://towardsdatascience.com/using-python-pandas-and-plotly-to-generate-nba-shot-charts-e28f873a99cb

The basic idea is put the data into a csv file.

So I try this code, to get the data from the nba web, trying to get the json file and the convert it to a csv:

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame as df
import urllib.request



shot_data_url_start="https://stats.nba.com/events/?flag=3&CFID=33&CFPARAMS=2017-18&PlayerID="
player_id="202695"
shot_data_url_end="&ContextMeasure=FGA&Season=2017-18&section=player&sct=plot"

def shoy_chart(player_id):
   full_url = shot_data_url_start + str(player_id) + shot_data_url_end
   json = requests.get(full_url, headers=headers).json()
return(json)



data = json['resultSets'][0]['rowSets']
columns = json['resultSets'][0]['headers']


df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data, columns=columns)
```

And this is the error that notebook shows to me:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-a3452c3a4fc8> in <module>
 18 
 19 
 ---> 20 data = json['resultSets'][0]['rowSets']
 21 columns = json['resultSets'][0]['headers']
 22 

 TypeError: 'module' object is not subscriptable
```

Anyone can help me, or know another way to get the data into a .csv or excel file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When imported with `import json`, the name `json` is referring to the JSON module of the Python standard library. You cannot use it as a regular variable name. If you rename your variable to something else such as `response_json`, this part of your code will work.

Regarding the rest of the code, the page https://stats.nba.com/events/ doesn't return any JSON text, it is a regular web page with images, menus, a video player, etc... If you want to access the API that returns the shots in JSON format, you will have to use the https://stats.nba.com/stats/shotchartdetail (with the right query string). This API endpoint is mentioned in the tutorial, in the "Chrome XHR tab and resulting json linked by url" image.

Comment: Hi @Pierre, thanks for the answer, but I don't get you... I've tried changing the json to response_json and is the same error, or "response_json" is not defined..

Comment: you were right, I was using other page..., do you know how from that I can convert the json into a csv?

Comment: Sure, I will give more details. When you use `import json` at the top of the file, the Python interpreter reserves the usage of the variable name `json` for the standard Python module for the rest of the execution of the script.

If you decide to choose the variable name `json` for one of your own variables, the Python interpreter will believe that you are referring to the `json` Python module, rather than your variable named `json`. This is actually what is done in the tutorial, and it is a bad practice. I will update my answer with some code.

Comment: To write the list of dicts you obtained from the JSON API call to a CSV file, you can use the Python [csv](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html) module.

Comment: Just one thing... now I don't have any error, I spaced the data variable and columns variable just below the return , it is ok ? or im missing something? it is like this

Comment: If you spaced all the code to be inside the `shoy_chat(player_id)` function, make sure to call it at the bottom of the script without any spacing.

Comment: take a look the other comment... I don't know what do you mean with call it at the bottom of the script--

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've changed the code like this:

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame as df
import urllib.request


def shot_chart(player_id):
full_url = "https://stats.nba.com/stats/shotchartdetail?AheadBehind=&CFID=33&CFPARAMS=2017-18&ClutchTime=&Conference=&ContextFilter=&ContextMeasure=FGA&DateFrom=&DateTo=&Division=&EndPeriod=10&EndRange=28800&GROUP_ID=&GameEventID=&GameID=&GameSegment=&GroupID=&GroupMode=&GroupQuantity=5&LastNGames=0&LeagueID=00&Location=&Month=0&OnOff=&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PORound=0&Period=0&PlayerID=202695&PlayerID1=&PlayerID2=&PlayerID3=&PlayerID4=&PlayerID5=&PlayerPosition=&PointDiff=&Position=&RangeType=0&RookieYear=&Season=2017-18&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular+Season&ShotClockRange=&StartPeriod=1&StartRange=0&StarterBench=&TeamID=0&VsConference=&VsDivision=&VsPlayerID1=&VsPlayerID2=&VsPlayerID3=&VsPlayerID4=&VsPlayerID5=&VsTeamID="
    response_json = requests.get(full_url, headers=headers)
    return(response_json)



    data = response_json['resultSets'][0]['rowSets']
    columns = response_json['resultSets'][0]['headers']


    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data, columns=columns)
```

Comment: @Pierre like this??

Comment: if I don't use the spacing notebook shows me the error that response_json is not defined

Comment: You need to space `full_url` as well so it is inside the `short_chart(player_id)` function. You also need to call this function at the bottom of the program without spacing: `short_chart("202695")`.

Comment: yes , the full_url was my mistake, but if  I put the shot_chart("202695") or what ever, notebook show me this: 
---> 15     response_json = requests.get(full_url, headers=headers).json()
     16     return(response_json)
     17 

NameError: name 'headers' is not defined>

Comment: You can remove the `headers=headers`, as this GET request only uses the query string.

Comment: I think something is wrong... I will post you the full code in other comment

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame as df
import urllib.request



shot_data_url_start="https://stats.nba.com/stats/shotchartdetail?AheadBehind=&CFID=33&CFPARAMS=2019-20&ClutchTime=&Conference=&ContextFilter=&ContextMeasure=FGA&DateFrom=&DateTo=&Division=&EndPeriod=10&EndRange=28800&GROUP_ID=&GameEventID=&GameID=&GameSegment=&GroupID=&GroupMode=&GroupQuantity=5&LastNGames=0&LeagueID=00&Location=&Month=0&OnOff=&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PORound=0&Period=0&PlayerID="
player_id="202330"
shot_data_url_end="&PlayerID1=&PlayerID2=&PlayerID3=&PlayerID4=&PlayerID5=&PlayerPosition=&PointDiff=&Position=&RangeType=0&RookieYear=&Season=2019-20&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular+Season&ShotClockRange=&StartPeriod=1&StartRange=0&StarterBench=&TeamID=0&VsConference=&VsDivision=&VsPlayerID1=&VsPlayerID2=&VsPlayerID3=&VsPlayerID4=&VsPlayerID5=&VsTeamID="

def shot_chart(player_id):
    full_url = shot_data_url_start + str(player_id) + shot_data_url_end
    response_json = requests.get(full_url).json()
    return(response_json)



    data = response_json['resultSets'][0]['rowSets']
    columns = response_json['resultSets'][0]['headers']


    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data, columns=columns)

shot_chart("202330")
```

What is going on now? the notebook is tucked right know

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame as df

shot_data_url_start = "https://stats.nba.com/stats/shotchartdetail?AheadBehind=&CFID=33&CFPARAMS=2017-18&ClutchTime=&Conference=&ContextFilter=&ContextMeasure=FGA&DateFrom=&DateTo=&Division=&EndPeriod=10&EndRange=28800&GROUP_ID=&GameEventID=&GameID=&GameSegment=&GroupID=&GroupMode=&GroupQuantity=5&LastNGames=0&LeagueID=00&Location=&Month=0&OnOff=&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PORound=0&Period=0&PlayerID="
player_id = "204001"
shot_data_url_end = "&PlayerID1=&PlayerID2=&PlayerID3=&PlayerID4=&PlayerID5=&PlayerPosition=&PointDiff=&Position=&RangeType=0&RookieYear=&Season=2017-18&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular+Season&ShotClockRange=&StartPeriod=1&StartRange=0&StarterBench=&TeamID=0&VsConference=&VsDivision=&VsPlayerID1=&VsPlayerID2=&VsPlayerID3=&VsPlayerID4=&VsPlayerID5=&VsTeamID="

def get_shot_data(player_id):
    full_url = shot_data_url_start + player_id + shot_data_url_end
    data = requests.get(
        full_url,
        headers = {
            "User-Agent": "PostmanRuntime/7.4.0"
        }
    )
    return data.json()

shot_results = get_shot_data(player_id)

result_sets = shot_results['resultSets']

first_result_set = result_sets[0]
row_set = first_result_set['rowSet']
set_headers = first_result_set['headers']

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(row_set, columns=set_headers)
```

I see how you got confused with that medium post. You were missing the `headers` and the url for the NBA api wasn't right. That's what @pierre was trying to say in his response. The url you're using isn't right. If you reread that post you were following, you'll see that the author said he had to dig in to dev tools in order to find that actual url to use in order to grab the JSON.

Edit: Forgot to mention that when I didn't pass a `User-Agent` in the `headers`, the request would timeout. If you don't pass that in, you won't get a successful response.

Comment: thanks Anthony! only add that need to import the requests module. Perfect!! now I need to know how transform the json into a csv, keep looking.

Comment: No problem, yea sorry about omitting `requests` up top.

Since it seems like this question has been taken care of, maybe you should start a new one going? I don't mind helping you out with that one also.